# How to set up a ListView's "onItemSelectedListener" within a dialog. Android

Tags: android, listview, dialog, listener, android-listview

Hey guys I got a ListView within a dialog set up however when i set up the onItemSelectedListener in the dialog it does not even register that anything is selected within the ListView in the dialog! Any ideas? here is what i have:

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DealActivity.this);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.test_list);
 dialog.setTitle("Test Dialog");
 dialog.setCancelable(true);
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
 ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);

 //DIDNT INCLUDE CODE HERE THAT SETS UP THE ADAPTER! 
 //THIS IS WHERE I SET UP THE LISTENER WITHIN THE DIALOG.

 listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {                              

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Log.d("clicked","clicked "+ listView.getItemSelectedPosition());
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
}
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to listen to the event when you touch list items? if so, then try listview.setOnItemClickListener(...)

Comment: I have EXACTLY this problem... How did you manage to fix it? The appointed solution is not working for me... I also dont have any kind of buttons inside the list items.. So it doesnt seem to be the focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

If you have some controls with each item in ListView, like CheckBox, Button,etc, add this to its layout xml.

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```